# Reformat ternary operator

Tags: visual-studio-code

The default reformatting is working unexpectedly.

What I want:

[image]

After Reformatting:

[image]

How can I config the reformatting so that it works as I expect?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but if your ternary is so long that you feel the need to break it into multiple lines, that's no good sign.

Comment: @Tamás It's normal in JSX that ternary is very long like below: `return ({isMyComponent ? <MyComponent style={...} prop1={...} prop2={...} ... /> : <OtherComponent style={...} otherProp1={...} otherProp2={...}/>})`

Comment: I'd set up const's before the render to represent each component so that your ternary can be `return ({isMyComponent ? MyComponent : OtherComponent})` so that the emphasis is on the ternary itself; it's easier to read this way. But it's up to one's taste, so yea, I'm not trying to tell what's a good way to go about it.

Comment: @Tamás That's true. We are just following the style I pointed out.

Comment: Even if the tenary is short, I liek to format it as `var stuff = condition <linebreak> ? value1 <linebreak> : value2;` and not in a single line. For me too, the standard formatting in VS code is unsatisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue we the TypeScript formatter. We are tracking the fix here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14494